# prove that every graph with $n\ge7$ vertices and at least 5n-14 edges contains a sub graph with minimum degree at least 6

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

**Question:**
prove that every graph with $n\ge7$ vertices and at least 5n-14 edges contains a sub graph with minimum degree at least 6.

**My proof:**
By induction. For n=7, the number of edges is 21=$7 \choose 2$ which implies this is the full graph, so each degree is 6, and therefore the min degree as well.
Now using the induction hypothesis, proof for n:
A graph G with n vertices and 5n-14 edges, can actually be thought of as a graph G' with n-1 vertices with 5(n-1)-14=5n-21 edges, with an added vertex and 7 added edges. Since the hypothesis is true for n-1, then adding this vertex and the 7 edges won't decrease the min degree.

I want to know if this proof suffices or am I missing something?

Comment: "with an added vertex and 7 added edges" - how do you determine thes seven edges?

Comment: I'm assuming I have a graph with 5n-14 edges (n sized), but I can also look at it as an n-1 sized graph with 5(n-1)-14 edges + 7 edges and a vertex. Can't I?

Comment: Can you obtain $K_{100}$ from a graph with $99$ vertices by adding a vertex and seven edges?

Comment: $5(n-1)-14 = 5n-19$, not $5n-21$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the induction step: Consider $G$ with $n$ vertices.
If all vertices of $G$ have degree $\ge 6$, $G$ itself is a subgraph as required.
Otherwise, $G$ has a vertex $v$ of degree $\le 5$, and then $G':=G-v$ has $n-1$ vertices and $5n-14-\rho(v)\ge 5(n-1)-14$ edges, hence by induction hypotheses $G$' contains a subgraph with minimum degree $\ge 6$. As this is also a subgraph of $G$, we are done.

Answer (score 2):

Let $G=(V,E)$ be a graph of order $n\ge7$. If every subgraph has a vertex of degree $\lt6$, then we can list the vertices as $V=\{v_1,\dots,v_n\}$ where $v_i$ has degree $f_i\lt6$ in the subgraph induced by $\{v_i,\dots,v_n\}$. Since $f_i\le5$ for all $i$, and since $f_n+f_{n-1}+f_{n-2}+f_{n-3}+f_{n-4}\le0+1+2+3+4=10$, it follows that
$|E|=f_1+\cdots+f_n\le5(n-5)+10=5n-15\lt5n-14$. Therefore, if $|E|\ge5n-14$, then $G$ must have a subgraph with minimum degree $\ge6$.

More generally, if $G=(V,E)$ is a graph of order $|V|=n\gt d$, and if $|E|\gt(d-1)n-\binom d2$, then $G$ has a subgraph with minimum degree at least $d$.

Comment: Choose $v_1$ of degree $\le5$ in $G$. Then choose $v_2$ of degree $\le5$ in $G-v_1$. Then choose $v_3$ of degree $\le5$ in $G-v_1-v_2$. Continue in this way until all vertices have been listed.

Comment: $$|E|=\sum_{i=1}^nf_i\le\sum_{i=1}^n\min(5,n-i)=\sum_{i=1}^{n-5}5+\sum_{i=n-4}^n(n-i)=5(n-5)+10=5n-15$$

Comment: $f_i$ is the degree of $v_i$ in the subgraph of $G$ induced by $\{v_i,\dots,v_n\}$, that is, $f_i$ is the number of edges in $G$ of the form $v_iv_j$ with $i$ fixed and $j\gt i$, so each edge of $G$ is counted exactly once in $\sum f_i$.